# Unable to Docker to port forward nuxt based express server to host

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am using Docker for Windows (Windows 10 is at 2004 so I have got WSL2) and I am trying to containerise a Nuxt application. The application runs well on my local system and after creating a Dockerfile and building it, I cannot get it to port forward onto my host system. Whereas, when trying the same when sample applications from https://github.com/BretFisher/docker-mastery-for-nodejs/tree/master/ultimate-node-dockerfile (the Dockerfile from the `test` folder is supposed to be used), I can access the same.

If I `exec` into my running container, I am able to get the output on running `curl http://localhost:3000` so things are supposedly fine.

My Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM node:12.18.3-buster-slim
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors=sayak@redacted.com
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R node:node /app
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qy \
    ca-certificates \
    bzip2 \
    curl \
    libfontconfig \
    --no-install-recommends
USER node
RUN npm config list
RUN npm ci \
    && npm cache clean --force
ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN nuxt build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD ["node", "server/index.js"]
```

I have even tried by removing all `chown`s and removing `USER node` to run it as `root` but to no avail.

This is the output to `docker ps -a`

```
d727c8dd4d5c        my-container:1.2.3   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes               0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   inspiring_dhawan
c3a5aac8b79f        sample-node-app      "/tini -- node serve…"   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   tender_ardinghelli
```

The `sample-node-app` from the above GitHub link works whereas my `my-container` doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have tried building and running the containers in an Ubuntu VM but I get the same result, so its not an issue with WSL or Windows but something is wrong with my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 9):

By default, Nuxt development server host is **'localhost'**, but **it is only accessible from within** the host machine.
So, to tell Nuxt to resolve a host address, which is accessible to connections outside of the host machine, e.g. **Ubuntu Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2)**, you must use host **'0.0.0.0'**

You can fix this by adding the following code to the `nuxt.config.js` file :

```js
  export default {
    server: {
      port: 3000,     // default : 3000
      host: '0.0.0.0' // do not put localhost (only accessible from the host machine)
      },
    ...
  }
```

See [Nuxt FAQ about Host Port](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/) for more information.

Comment: WORKED FOR M!!!

Comment: or ./node_modules/.bin/nuxt -H 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Nuxt changes the default address the server listens to from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 and Docker can only port forward from 0.0.0.0.