# Dockerized nginx and vue+nuxt cannot connect to frontend server 111: Connection refused

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

When trying to access localhost in the browser I get 502 bad gateway
in the docker container logs the following error:

```
failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.26.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.26.0.5:3000/", host: "localhost"
```

Below is the nginx.conf file:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:3000;
    }

    upstream api {
        server api:8000;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./backend/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf # Mount the Nginx config file
        depends_on:
            - api
            - frontend
    api:
        build:
            context: ./backend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-8000}:80'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/'
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    frontend:
        tty: true
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: frontend
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/app
        depends_on:
            - api
        stdin_open: true
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        volumes:
            - 'mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql'
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - "1025:1025"
            - "8025:8025"
volumes:
    mysql_data:
        driver: local
```

**Debugging steps:**

1. check the ip address - docker container inspect frontend - address matches

- Docker container inspect shows ->"IPAddress": "172.26.0.5",
- The nginx error message says: "http://172.26.0.5:3000/"

2. frontend container running without any errors in logs - last log is that its listening on 3000
3. log in to the nginx container: docker container exec -it nginx sh

- ping frontend -->success - no packets lost
- ping api -->success - no packets lost
- so the nginx.conf must be fine, after all it resolves successfully to the upstreams defined as "frontend" and "api"

4. the above test means they are in the same network and everything should be fine in terms of docker internal networking and name resolution

At this point Nginx seems to be properly configured and able to communicate with the upstreams by ping but cannot properly establish connection with the frontend when needs to route a request.

Maybe the issue roots in some nuxt/vue configuration for CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's too late to solve your problem, but nuxt has to be configured properly to accept connections from an outside network. Otherwise it refuses every connection that ist not from the host machine.
You can set the "HOST" variable in your docker environment OR in the nuxt config:

In docker-compose.yaml:

```
environment:
      HOST: 0
      PORT: 3000
```

Or in nuxt.config.js:

```
server: {
    port: 3000,     
    host: '0.0.0.0' // do not put localhost (only accessible from the host machine)
   }
```

The answer to this question helped me:
[Unable to Docker to port forward nuxt based express server to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209109/unable-to-docker-to-port-forward-nuxt-based-express-server-to-host)